# Registration failed for type 'core-toolbar', already registered

Tags: polymer

I'm loading scripts:

```
html(ng-app="app")
    head
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/angular/angular.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/requirejs/require.js', type='text/javascript', data-main='js/Main.js')
        script(language='javascript', src='http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/platform/platform.js', type='text/javascript')
        //link(rel="import", href="elements/elements.html" )
        link(rel="import", href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" )
        link(rel="import", href="bower_components/core-component-page/core-component-page.html" )
        link(rel='import', href='bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html')
        link(rel='import', href='bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html')
        link(rel='import', href='bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html')
        link(rel='import', href='bower_components/core-menu/core-toolbar.html')
        link(rel='import', href='bower_components/core-item/core-item.html')
```

but get

```
 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'core-toolbar'. A type with that name is already registered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you import `core-component-page` which is a vulcanized version of a whole bunch of core components (i.e. it already defines `core-header-panel`, `core-toolbar` and so on.)

So either use this import only (plus the components that are not defined in this file) or remove this line and import each component on its own (which is the way i prefer, so i know exactly which components get loaded in to my app.)

Btw. there's a typo in your `core-toolbar` import. It must be `bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html`

Comment: exactly. core-component-pages should really only be used by itself to generate docs. don't mix it in with other elements, it'll just break things.